# Angular app on IE 11 failed to load module after grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

I can run my app perfectly on localhost using `grunt serve` on every browser (including Internet Explorer 11). I do a `grunt build`, deploy my app on Apache and everything works great on every browser except, of coarse, on Internet Explorer (11 on this case). I get this error on the console and the app won't even start:

`[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module portalApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pdf due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pdf' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`

I checked my minified vendors js file and the angular-pdf module (pdf) is present. The app makes use of it correctly on every other browser too.

My application module injection starts like this (if it helps):

`angular
  .module('portalApp', [
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'pdf',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'ngTagsInput',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'blockUI',
    'smart-table',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'tmh.dynamicLocale',
    'ui.sortable',
    'angular-tour',
    'gridster']);`

If I change the pdf module position on the list I get the same problem, but instead for the module gridster. No matter how I place them on the list there's always an error for one or another.

PS: I tried it on different computers and got the same issue. I'm starting to think that it has to do with the vendors file being too large and creating some kind of issue with the module loading, but that's strange always failing on the same modules.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find the answer to that problem ?

Comment: @MikeW not the clean way. I removed the minification and concat of the files on the grunt build. Somehow the IE didn't managed to "process" a single JS file with so many data. Don't know why

Comment: thanks for your answer. On my end I had some js errors that I could only see on my local machine. When I fixed those errors, everything worked fine.